# NodeJS route post always returns 404

Tags: node.js

I have this simple post route:

```
const exportRouter = new Router();

exportRouter.post('/my-post', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("This does not appear");
});
```

But when I run /my-post it hits my break point, does not do my console.log and it gives me a 404 error, why is it doing this and how can I fix it?

// koa setup
app.use(exportRouter.routes()).use(exportRouter.allowedMethods());

Comment: I don't think you need the "new"

Comment: You mean "next" ?

Comment: Even with "next" removed it still does not work

Comment: What you are doing with `exportRouter`? Please provide a [mcve].